# Java: This should be O(n), maybe an ArrayList problem?

Tags: java, arraylist, runtime, big-o

I have some code that I believe to run in O(n), however when I time it, it seems to run in polynomial time.  I'm trying to process ~200,000 records, so I did it in blocks of size `MAX_COUNT` so I wouldn't run out of heap space.  That is, during the processing phase, a few things take place that make the records increase dramatically in size.

I copied in the important parts from my code.  I feel like something is going on here that has to do with ArrayLists that I just don't understand.

This might not be the smartest way to go about things, but I don't see why it's taking longer to process each block than the previous.  That is, each bock is size 5000 (except the first block), but the 1st block processed takes ~5seconds, and the 20th block processed takes ~25seconds.  I would expect them to all take the same amount of time.

```
// Maximum block size
final int MAX_COUNT = 5000;

// Total number of records in need of processing
int n = records.size();

// the number of blocks to process
int numBlocks = (n / MAX_COUNT) + 1;
if (n % MAX_COUNT == 0) numBlocks--;

// The number of records to process in the block.
int numRecords;
ArrayList<Record> recordBlock = null;


// Iterate backwards through the blocks.
for (int i = numBlocks; i > 0; i--) {
    // Make sure we don't process too many records.
    if ( (i == 1 && numBlocks = 1 && n % MAX_COUNT != 0) ||
         (i == numBlocks && n % MAX_COUNT != 0) )
        numRecords = n % MAX_COUNT;
    else numRecords = MAX_COUNT;

    recordBlock = new ArrayList<Record>();

    //EDIT: Fixed loop syntax (typo!)
    for (int j = numRecords -1; j >= 0; j--)
        recordBlock.add(records.remove(j));

    recordBlock = ThreadHelper.processRecords(recordBlock,true,true);

    while (recordBlock.size() != 0) {
        Record r = recordBlock.remove(recordBlock.size() -1);
        // write 'r' to MySQL
    }

 }
```

Comment: Why the drive-by-downvote?  Question seems reasonable enough, would be nice if the downvoter would leave a reason.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not running low on a system resource (most particularly memory)?  Things that should be linear in an ideal world often aren't because of resource contention as `n` gets bigger.

Comment: i'm pretty sure some garbage collection needs to take place after a while, but i mean... is there a way to check if I'm running out?

Comment: 2 nested loop mostly is an indicator for non-linearity

Comment: I figured using the backing array would still indicate O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @mcfinnigan

```
recordBlock = new ArrayList<Record>(numRecords);
```

In addition, replace

```
while (recordBlock.size() != 0) {            
    Record r = recordBlock.remove(recordBlock.size() -1);            
    // write 'r' to MySQL        
}
```

by

```
for (Record r: recordBlock) {// write 'r' to MySQL }
recordBlock.clear();
```

Comment: does the `clear()` cause the arraylist to get reallocated in memory?

Comment: There is no reallocation. The allocated elements are marked as garbage and the list size is set to 0.

Answer (score 3):

This section

```
for (int j = numRecords -1; j >= j--)
        recordBlock.add(records.remove(j));
```

will reallocate the backing array behind recordBlock every time the backing array is filled.  Rather declare it as

```
recordBlock = new ArrayList<Record>(numRecords);
```

Also, the loop syntax is incorrect.

Comment: I am confused as to what `new ArrayList<Record>(numRecords) will do?  Won't that also realloc?

Comment: However the growth of the backing array itself is `n^2` so it *amortizes* to `O(1)` fairly well... I can't imagine this is the entire problem, although it won't hurt.

Comment: @theangryhornet - by declaring it as such outside the loop, you ensure the ArrayList is of the correct size to accept all incoming records without needing reallocation.

Comment: @theangryhornet The idea is to only have the ArrayList *backing* array allocated once -- with the total size. `add` can cause a realloc if the backing array is too small (a new array of double capacity is created and the old data copied over) so `add` is only *amortized* to `O(1)`. I'm not sure I buy this as the problem, but the change wouldn't hurt and it would be interesting to see if anything changes...

Comment: alright, so if I initalized once outside my `for()` would a `clear()` still dealloc?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the for loop adding to the recordBlock.

```
for (int j = numRecords -1; j >= j--)
    recordBlock.add(records.remove(j));
```

should be

```
for (int j = numRecords -1; j >= 0; j--)
    recordBlock.add(records.remove(j));
```

If I am not mistaken.

Edit:

Another mistake I found was in your if statement.

```
if ( (i == 1 && numBlocks = 1 && n % MAX_COUNT != 0) ||
     (i == numBlocks && n % MAX_COUNT != 0) )
```

should be

```
if ( (i == 1 && numBlocks == 1 && n % MAX_COUNT != 0) ||
     (i == numBlocks && n % MAX_COUNT != 0) )
```

Might I suggest simplifying it to:

```
if(i == numBlocks && n % MAX_COUNT != 0)
```

since the first condition is just a special case when i = 1.

Comment: You are correct. I typed out these parts from my code by hand. I didn't want to just n00b it up with a copy and paste.  It would have been too much for anyone to process.  But it is so in my code.

Comment: As for the second edit.  I don't think I can simplify it, as the special case is when `i==1` AND there is only one block.  Clearly, next post, I'm going to have to be much more careful about syntax errors.

Comment: I am pretty sure it can; logically speaking, the first case you check, (i == 1 && numBlocks == 1) is included in the (i == numBlocks) check. I am certain that the first statement is a redundant check.

Comment: You are correct. I had a little trouble seeing the logic, but I got it now :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the real code has if and for statements without braces then what you think the code does may not actually be what it does.